# 503 Backend Fetch when Uploading. Varnish?

Tags: php, html, css, upload

I have no idea what Varnish is and I do not know how to set it up and all that or how to fix this. I did look p the answers but I didnt understand. I run a website at www.darksouls.uk and when I go to the videos section to check the upload button, it gives me this

> Error 503 Backend fetch failed

Backend fetch failed

Guru Meditation:

XID: 666796545

Varnish cache server

And I have no idea how to fix this, what it means and what I do know, is that about a month or 2 ago, it worked perfectly fine. This happens whenever I test my simplistic, php upload script that I found on w3schools. Any ideas and answers appreciated. ;) Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: Do you need Varnish? If not, don't use it. If you do need it: varnish is trying to get something from your server, but is not getting it back.

Comment: I havent installed anythhing. I dont even know what varnish is! It worked one day, and the ned day it didnt

Comment: Then your host might have. Ask them. What is the URL of your website?

Comment: Try post a video and 503 happens

Comment: I upload a 1MB video to http://www.darksouls.uk/upload_fileV.php

and I get a succes:
By uploading you agree to give me full rights to whatever you are uploading.Success

50MB also works. Did you try uploading from another computer and from another location?

Comment: Yes i did and some others tried too. The videobi was tryong to uploadbwas 717.14mb big

Comment: And your PHP settings reflect that that can be handled? post size, time limit, etc?

Comment: yes, i have managed to do the same thing on earlier occasions